# Синтаксическая ошибка PHP : syntax error, unexpected '='

Tags: php

вот строка с ошибкой :

```
 result = mysqli_query ("SELECT * FROM 'news' ORDER BY 'id' DESC LIMIT  $limit");
```

вот весь код:

```
 $mysqli = false;
 function connectDB() {
     global $mysqli;
     $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "myste");

 }
 function closeDB () {
     global $mysqli;
     $mysqli_close ();
 }
 function getNews ($limit) {
     global $mysqli;
     connectDB();
     result = mysqli_query ("SELECT * FROM 'news' ORDER BY 'id' DESC LIMIT  $limit");
     closeDB();
     return resultToArray ($result);
 }
 function resultToArray ($result) {
     $array = array();
     while (($row = $result_fetch_assoc()) != false)
         $array[] = $row;
     return $array;
 }
```

?>

Comment: Где `$` в обозначении переменной? И сюда загляните http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php На количество параметров функции в процедурном стиле обратите внимание.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не обозначили переменную $result, вместо

```
result = mysqli_query ("SELECT * FROM 'news' ORDER BY 'id' DESC LIMIT  $limit");
```

напишите

```
$result = mysqli_query ("SELECT * FROM 'news' ORDER BY 'id' DESC LIMIT  $limit");
```

Comment: не сработает из-за `'` у названий

Answer (score 0):

$limit заключить в кавычки '$limit', если не сработает news и id - заключить в обратные кавычки( та что на букве Ё) `news` и `id`

Comment: Можно вообще кавычки убрать